# np.linalg.inv() giving unexpected results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, inverse

I'm using numpy to inverse a matrix but are getting some unexpected results.

Running my program I get an end result of p1 as:

```
>>> p1
array([[1.69133481e+11, 3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06],
       [3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04],
       [8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02],
       [1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02, 2.00000000e+01]])
```

Then when I try to inverse p1 using np.linalg.inv() I get:

```
>>> np.linalg.inv(p1)
array([[ 2.33378273e+00, -3.16566294e+02,  1.43119558e+04,
        -2.15657094e+05],
       [-3.16566293e+02,  4.29411791e+04, -1.94139249e+06,
         2.92538609e+07],
       [ 1.43119557e+04, -1.94139249e+06,  8.77723669e+07,
        -1.32261292e+09],
       [-2.15657092e+05,  2.92538606e+07, -1.32261291e+09,
         1.99302540e+10]])
```

Which is obviously incorrect as:

```
>>> (p1 @ np.linalg.inv(p1))
array([[ 9.99968764e-01, -1.28189335e-03, -7.44723976e-01,
         3.60136516e+00],
       [-2.53043124e-06,  9.99986814e-01, -3.83602548e-02,
         1.12390996e-01],
       [-8.71254524e-08,  9.18930849e-06,  9.99317258e-01,
         4.33950341e-03],
       [-6.98491931e-10,  7.45058060e-08, -1.23977661e-05,
         1.00001526e+00]])
>>> (p1 @ np.linalg.inv(p1)).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

My result is clearly not the identity matrix.

However, this is where things get weirder. If I redefine p1 with the values printed to the terminal when typing "p1" and compute the same commands as before I get:

```
>>> p1 = np.array([[1.69133481e+11, 3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06],
...        [3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04],
...        [8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02],
...        [1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02, 2.00000000e+01]])
>>> p1 @ np.linalg.inv(p1)
array([[ 9.99999999e-01, -4.85794104e-07, -2.14803652e-05,
        -4.95130838e-04],
       [ 2.61335278e-10,  9.99999940e-01,  9.92065715e-07,
        -3.11477404e-05],
       [ 1.87780333e-13, -5.48610778e-10,  1.00000001e+00,
        -1.02864912e-07],
       [ 9.94759830e-14, -2.00088834e-11,  5.82076609e-10,
         9.99999998e-01]])
>>> (p1 @ np.linalg.inv(p1)).astype(int)
array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Here, the result is pretty much in line with what expected as I get the identity matrix.

The fact the matrix inverse is not correct before redefining p1 is causing problems in my code. Any ideas?

Comment: what is `np.linalg.det(p1)`?   I suspect `p1` is close to singular, the actual array more so than the recreated one.

Comment: Can you share more details on how exactly is this causing problems in your code?

Comment: @hpaulj np.linalg.det(p1) is: 99.53509638901218

Comment: @FelipeLanza I'm writing a program to calculate polynomial regression on a set of points. I'm using the equation np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) @ X.T @ y to calculate the weights. However, once the polynomial reaches a certain order np.linalg.inv(X.T @ X) giving an unexpected (possibly wrong) value which causes the weights to be inaccurate (I think). This means the curve I am plotting is not even close to the points.

Comment: Compared to the largest value in `p1` that is small.  The `det` for the reconstructed array is larger, `1193590`

Comment: @hpaulj So what's causing these differences? Floating point accuracies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is correct, your issue is with the floating point (in)accuracy:

```
In [1]: arr = np.array([[1.69133481e+11, 3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06], 
   ...:        [3.74575030e+09, 8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04], 
   ...:        [8.29681977e+07, 1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02], 
   ...:        [1.83800903e+06, 4.07236156e+04, 9.02416997e+02, 2.00000000e+01]])                                     

In [2]: inv = np.linalg.inv(arr)                                                                                      

In [3]: np.isclose(arr @ inv, np.eye(*arr.shape), atol=1e-3)                                                          
Out[3]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True]])
```